# jQuery character replacement call activated on click

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery function to automatically replace sertain characters with others:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.textarea').keyup(function() {

    jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().replace(/A/g, "5"));
    jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().replace(/Q/g, "3"));

    });
});
```

I want to make this function optional and only activated if the user clicks on a button next the text-area input form.

I'm trying something like this:

```
$("a").toggle(
  function () {

        jQuery(function() {
            jQuery('.tifibox').keyup(function() {

            jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().replace(/A/g, "3"));
            jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().replace(/Q/g, "5"));

            });
        });

    $(this).addClass("selected"); // button selected
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
  }
);
```

I have not tested this yet.. but is that correct? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the link to a checkbox and then you can use something like:

```
$("#checkOne").change(   function () {
      if($(this).is(":checked")) {
         $("#textOne").bind("keyup", function() {
              $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/A/g, "3"));
         });
      } else {
          $("#textOne").unbind("keyup");
      }   }

);
```

[The jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDyn3/2/)

This code will only replace newly typed text and old text will remain unchanged.
If you want to replace the existing text (i.e. escape the existing text, modify the code as follows:

```
$("#checkOne").change(
  function () {
      var textarea = $("#textOne");
      if($(this).is(":checked")) {
         escapeText($(textarea));
         $(textarea).bind("keyup", function() {
              escapeText($(this));
         });
      } else {
          $(textarea).unbind("keyup");
      }
  }

);

function escapeText(ele) {
    $(ele).val($(ele).val().replace(/A/g, "3"));
}
```

the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDyn3/3/)

Of course you can use a link as well, but the syntax is confusing. `toggle()` takes 3 parameters (3 functions):

1 - handler(eventObject)A function to execute every even time the element is clicked.

2 - handler(eventObject)A function to execute every odd time the element is clicked.

3 - handler(eventObject)Additional handlers to cycle through after clicks.

So in your code above, the first click would call the second function (since one it's odd) the second you call the first function. So turn on the feature in the second function and turn it off in the first.

Also use `bind` and `unbind` as I have shown rather than setting classes.

Comment: thanks for the code, I added a checkbox above the textarea with #myCheckbox ID, and in the "replace code here" comment I added the replace functions: `jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().replace(/A/g, "3"));` but the character replacement didn't occur when I checked the box.. did I miss something here?..

Comment: Works fine. Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZDyn3/1/ when I type an uppercase `A` it's replaced with `3` (if the checkbox is checked). If the checkbox is not checked `A` will remain `A`. I think you want to replace all current text if the checkbox is checked and continue to replace text if the checkbox is checked. Is that correct? The code as it is, doesn't change the current text only newly typed text.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked now after I added: `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: I have multiple textareas in the same page, so the only problem is that it works only for the first textarea input field.. do you have any idea if it could work with multiple textareas? thanks again

Comment: sorry I didn't make myself clear on the problem, what I mean is that each textarea has its own checkbox, so it doesn't work when I check the checkbox under other textareas to replace characters; it works for the first checkbox only. also the first checkbox if selected is affecting characters to be replaced in other textareas which is not what I want.. I have 3 textareas so I want them to be independent and only change characters if the checkbox under it is selected.. thanks again

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right way but I duplicated the call to the replace function like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDyn3/46/

Comment: There is nothing wrong with doing this per-say. There is a lot of code duplication here, there is a better way to do this to remove the duplication. I'll get back to you on this in a little bit.

Comment: [Here is one solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDyn3/56/) that assumes that (a) your html will change a lot so doesn't depend on your DOM strucutre (b) you don't have a lot of text area's and checkboxes (so it's okay to bind each checkbox individually) if there are a lot of them you should change it so you don't have to bind each checkbox in turn. However I would need a lot more details on your html to be able to do that.

Comment: ok, I have a commenting page with the main textarea for comments, but it generate another textarea and shows it when a user clicks on replay.. so in totall I have two textareas; one fixed with an IP and CLASS, no problem with this one. The other generated textarea gets the same class ".textTwo" but different generated IDs, so the replace function works with the first fixed texarea and the first generated textarea (the other generated text areas are ignored even they get the class ".textTwo")..! I tried you last solution but still didn't work for other generated textareas.. any idea?

Comment: okay, can you give me the exact html for both? We can probably solve your problem by making detecting the textareas position relative to your checkbox. So we bind all checkboxes and each checkbox will only escape the textarea that is it's sibling. Get the idea? Also, `bind` does not work for dynamically added element which may be the problem. Use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead. `live' will bind all current and future elements meeting your criteria.

Comment: I replace the bind/unbide with .live and .die and it works only like before.. the problem is only with generated textareas.. I like the idea about textareas position relative to your checkbox, and here is html for two generated forms :

Comment: `<form>
<div class="ac-reply-avatar">
<img height="25" width="25" src="../avatars/1/f0b0fa43eb9bthumb.jpg" alt="" class="avatar"></div>
<div class="ac-reply-content">
     <div class="ac-textarea">
 <textarea id="ac-input-132" class="tifitwo" name="ac_input_132"></textarea>
         <div class="tificheckbox">
               <label><input type="checkbox" id="checktwo">Tifi</label>
         </div>
 <input type="submit" name="ac_form_submit" value="reply">
 <input type="hidden" name="comment_form_id" value="132">
 </div>
</div></form>`

Comment: this textarea is generated when a user clicks reply to a comment:
`<div class="ac-textarea">
 <textarea name="ac_input_113" class="tifitwo" id="ac-input-113"></textarea>
</div>`
you can see here that both textareas have the same class but different #ip

Comment: can you please start a jsfiddle it's possible for me to see what you are saying like this. Or upload a page where I can see what you are talking about.

Comment: Try [this soultion](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDyn3/79/) it no longer uses id's all checkboxes have a common css class (called 'common') and the checkboxes are bound using `live` this why when a checkbox with the class `common` will be added dynamically, it'll automatically be bound to the `onChange` event. The `textarea` to escape is determined by traversing up the DOM till we find a `textarea`. For further correspondance please contact me on my email (get it from the [contact me](http://alimuzaffar.com/index.php/contact-me) page on my site) this thread is too long.

Comment: I have changed the html to make checkboxes immediately under the textarea and now it works as expected.. you did it man! thank you so much